# How to set Custom tooltip event with Chartjs version 2.X

Tags: javascript, graph, click, chart.js, event-listener

Hi I am trying to attach click event on datapoints with `Chart.js` line graph.

However, the official document does not have such an information. I found some source which make custom events on tooltip, but they looks like using version 1.X.([add custom event on chartjs](http://jsfiddle.net/s8z60kes/1/)) - at version 2.x, can not access `Chart.defaults` -

So what I have to do is something like below.

- I will add `click` event on data points of `Chart.js` line graph
- `hover` event will be remain.

FYI, the codes I am trying to write is here.

```
function makeGraphSuitableData(items, type){
    var object = {
        labels : []
        , data : []
    }
    if(type == 'month') {
        object.labels = ["01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"];
        object.data = new Array(12);
        for(var i = 0; i < object.labels.length; i++) {
            var datas = items.filter(function(item){
                return (item.reg_month == object.labels[i]);
            })
            console.log('datas', datas);

            if(datas && datas.length > 0){
                var single = datas[0];
                object.data[(object.labels[i] * 1) - 1] = single.frequency;
            } else {
                object.data[(object.labels[i] * 1) - 1] = 0;
            }
        }
        object.labels = ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"];
    }
    return object;
}

function drawGraph(holder, statistics){

    var statistics = [
        {
            labels : "01"
            , frequency : "100"
        }, {
            labels : "02"
            , frequency : "150"
        }
    ]

    var canvas = holder.querySelector('canvas');
    if(!canvas){
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = 400; canvas.height = 150;
        holder.appendChild(canvas);
    }

    var graphObject = makeGraphSuitableData(statistics, 'month');

    // Bar-Graph
    var type = 'line';   //bar, line
    var displayLabel = 'Expose counts';

    switch (type){
        case 'line':
            var myChart = new Chart(canvas, {
                type: type,
                data: {
                    labels: graphObject.labels,
                    datasets: [{
                        label: displayLabel,
                        data: graphObject.data,
                        fill: false,
                        lineTension: 0,
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
                        borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                        borderCapStyle: 'butt',
                        borderDash: [],
                        borderDashOffset: 0.0,
                        borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
                        pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                        pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                        pointBorderWidth: 1,
                        pointHoverRadius: 5,
                        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                        pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                        pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
                        pointRadius: 1,
                        pointHitRadius: 10,
                        spanGaps: false
                    }]
                }
            });


            canvas.addEventListener('click', function(e){
                var x = myChart;
                window.x = x;
            }, false);
            break;
    }
}
```

Thanks for reading and your answers. `getPointsAtEvent` looks disappeared in version 2.X.

====== UPDATES 24MAR ======

To clear my point, I updated the post.
In my thought, in order to add click event on datapoints, need to get datapoints objects.

But I can not see how to access those points. 
I have examined the `Chart` object but could not find `getDataPoints()` or `getTooltips()`. Access to those object should be a solution, I guess.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/juneyoung/u4779f5c/17/)

Comment: I think you are assigning on click event to the chart while it doesn't exist. If you provide a link to jsfiddle or codpen it will be much easier for me to help you and resolve it :)

Comment: @alireza so here is my fiddle(https://jsfiddle.net/juneyoung/u4779f5c/17/). please reply if got an idea how to set click event on data point. thanks a lot. bb

Comment: What do you want to happen when you click? Make something appear, display the point data, etc.?

Comment: @jordanwillis i will change canvas to express bar graph when data point got a click event. (I want to display monthly line graph and bar graph of the month)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct (documented) way to do this, per [the api](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-prototype-methods), is to use the `.getElementAtEvent()` prototype method.

The other answer kind of works, but does not work if your chart has more than 1 dataset (e.g. line).  Plus, it relies on undocumented objects/properties in the chart.js object that could change at any time with a new release.

```
document.getElementById("canvas").onclick = function(evt){
  var activePoint = myChart.getElementAtEvent(event);

  // make sure click was on an actual point
  if (activePoint.length > 0) {
    var clickedDatasetIndex = activePoint[0]._datasetIndex;
    var clickedElementindex = activePoint[0]._index;
    var label = myChart.data.labels[clickedElementindex];
    var value = myChart.data.datasets[clickedDatasetIndex].data[clickedElementindex];     
    alert("Clicked: " + label + " - " + value);
  }
};
```

Here is a [codepen example](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/bqvLNx) demonstrating the above code.

Comment: I did not know there is `getElementAtEvent` event. Thanks for your answer and codepen!

Answer (score 0):

There is always a way to solve any issue. It took about half an hour but I found it.

in your jsfiddle, just change below:

```
canvas.addEventListener('click', function(e){
                var x = myChart;
}, false);
break;
```

to

```
canvas.addEventListener('click', function(e){
                var x = myChart;
                if(x.active[0]){
                    var value= x.tooltip._data.datasets["0"].data[x.active["0"]._index];
                    var label = x.tooltip._data.labels[x.active["0"]._index];
                    console.log(value + " at "+ label);
                }

}, false);
break;
```

You will have access to the point via `label` and `value`. enjoy :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer!